# Angular final release/version 2.0.1 page reload/refresh issue

Tags: angular2-routing

I have tried LocationStrategy in app.module.ts file with below code

```
    import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

    @NgModule({
        imports: [
            ...
        ],
        declarations: [
            ...
        ],
        bootstrap: [...],
        providers: [
            { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
        ]
    })

In app.component.ts file i have added below code
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

   export class AppComponent {
    constructor(location: Location) {
        location.go(location.path());
    }
}
```

But unable to identify while navigating to other page or on same page if I refresh page or press f5 page is not reloading instead its giving 404 page not found error.Can you please tell me solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have got same issue in my angular app with php after lots of solution found through goolge i tried this one- its working fine for me .

just put a .htaccess file in your root and add following code-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```